# Backmarking with backjumping(BMJ) algorithm

Tags: constraint-programming

I was reading a paper on Constraint Satisfaction using backmarking with buckjumping algorithm. In the paper , it was mentioned that back marking with backjumping does not result in the intended optimization.

In particular, this case was mentioned:

> Assume BMJ jumps from v[i], over v[h], to v[g], and does so when mbl[h]< g. When v[h] again becomes the current variable consistency checks will be repeated between v[h] and the variable v[x], where mbl[h]< x < g.Therefore we can only be sure that BMJ enjoys some of the advantages of BM.

In this case, if it were normal backmarking, how would this computation be avoided?

I found the following visual representation of the case.

[image]